# For loop not calling methods

Tags: java, for-loop, abstract

I have never been so confused about something so basic. In this instance, I have a for loop that is using an ArrayList for an abstract class. This class contains a few different update methods, all of which are being used for different classes that extend the abstract class and overwrite the methods. (I didn't include all of the update methods because I didn't think it was necessary, you should be able to guess what they are)

```
public abstract class Objs extends JComponent{

private int xpos;
private int ypos;
private int size;
private boolean ai;


public void update(){

}

public boolean getAI(){
    return ai;
}

public void update(int y, Container p){

}

public void update(int p, int x){

}
```

So, in the for loop I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objs.size() - 1; i++){

        objs.get(i).update(getParent());

        objs.get(i).update(getHeight(),(int)(objs.get(0).getYpos() - (.5 * objs.get(0).getS())));

        if(!(objs.get(i).getAI())){
            if(m[0])
                objs.get(i).update(1, getParent());
            if(m[1])
                objs.get(i).update(-1, getParent());
        }
    }
```

I have three different update methods. The first one works perfectly fine with my first class that is extending the abstract class. However, I have a second class using the second update method, and for some reason it seems like the method is not being called for that class. I honestly have no idea why not! What I have done for testing is outside of the for loop, called the method manually using the correct index and it works. So my only assumption left is that the For loop isn't calling the method for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: `i < objs.size() - 1` - is it intended that you don't update the last object?

Comment: Can you provide a [stripped-down, runnable example version of your code that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Remove or simplify anything you can without making it unrunnable or removing the bug, but leave anything that's actually necessary to demonstrate the problem. Right now, you're showing us too much of the code we don't need to see and not enough of the code we do.

Comment: You may with to switch to the alternate for-loop notation in this case, so that you don't have to use `objs.get(i)` constantly: `for (Objs obj : objs) {` (This does the same thing, but you can just use obj rather than having to constantly do `objs.get(i)`)

Comment: Did you try to run the program in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah try debugging step-by-step to observe where the control is going to, the values of variables, etc.

Comment: @AntonSavin, Since the ArrayList starts at 0, yes. Because objs.size() will return how large the array list is (In this case, just 2 for right now) however, I need to access objs.get(0) and objs.get(1), so I subtract 1 so that everything has the right index

Comment: @MagnusCaligo with that `- 1` in case of array size 2, you'll get only 0th element, think about it.

Comment: @ANtonSavin Ah, thank you, I was just following the steps of a program I mad a few weeks ago, which needed that -1 and I completely forgot about it!

Comment: If that solves your problem, then let us know, and perhaps delete this question as it will not likely help future visitors. If it does not solve your problem, then you will likely need to consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question has been solved and is not fit for other visitors!

Answer (score 0):

Since both update methods are working correctly when called outside of the loop but the second one is not working when called after the first I would suggest that you put the second update method before the first to see if it is just a matter of the second update method not being called. There is a possibility that alone could fix the problem.

However, if that doesn't fix the problem or if the second update method relies upon the first update method just put a print statement after the first update method. If that print statement doesn't print then the computer is most likely getting hung up on something in the first update method and isn't progressing to the second update method. If the print statement does print, however, my only guess is that something in the first update method is effecting the second update method. In that case, look through the first update method and check for any code that might cause a conflict with anything in the second update method.

I know this isn't necessarily a surefire fix for your problem but it ought to help you figure out what is causing the problem. Sadly, without the actual code i can't do much more. Anyway, good luck in figuring out your problem and I hope this helped!